# Querying an auto-generated EF junction table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two models, Benefit and SchemeName

Benefit -

```
[Key]
public int BenefitID { get; set; }
public string BenefitName { get; set; }
public string BenefitDescription { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SchemeName> SchemeNames { get; set; }
```

SchemeName

```
[Key]
public int SchemeNameID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Benefit> Benefits { get; set; }
```

This has created three tables in the database Benefits, SchemeNames and a joining table called SchemeNameBenefits.

I am trying to populate a droplownlist that contains only the SchemeNames associated with a certain Benefit but am not sure how I can do this, can I reference the join table in my code?

I started with the following (which returns all SchemeNames)

```
private void PopulatePensionSchemeName(object selectedPensionSchemeName = null)
        {
            var schemeNameQuery = from d in db.SchemeNames
                                  orderby d.SchemeNameID
                                  select d;

            ViewBag.PensionSchemeNameID = new SelectList(schemeNameQuery, "SchemeNameID", "Name", selectedPensionSchemeName);
        }
```

But I'm not sure how I can add this clause. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the key of the Benefit object you want the SchemeNames for. The query you're probably looking for is:-

```
var benefitId = // However you get your benefit Id

var schemaNameQuery = from b in db.Benefits
                      from s in b.SchemeNames
                      where b.BenefitId == benefitId
                      select s;
```

Or in the extension method syntax:-

```
var schemaNameQuery = db.Benefits.Where(b.BenefitId == benefitId)
                                 .SelectMany(b => b.SchemeNames);
```

Which produces the following SQL:-

```
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[SchemeNameBenefits] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SchemeNames] AS [Extent2]
  ON [Extent1].[SchemeName_Id] = [Extent2].[SchemeNameId]
WHERE [Extent1].[Benefit_Id] = @p__linq__0
```

Alternately you can use:-

```
var benefitId = // However you get your benefit Id

var schemeNameQuery = from d in db.SchemeNames
                      where d.Benefits.Any(x => x.Id == benefitId)
                      orderby d.SchemeNameId
                      select d;
```

This produces the following SQL:-

```
SELECT ...
FROM ( SELECT ... FROM [dbo].[SchemeNames] AS [Extent1]
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                     FROM [dbo].[SchemeNameBenefits] AS [Extent2]
                     WHERE ([Extent1].[SchemeNameId] = [Extent2].[SchemeName_Id])
                     AND ([Extent2].[Benefit_Id] = @p__linq__0)))
AS ...
ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] ASC
```

Note that in both cases the generated SQL references your junction table *even though it isn't part of your EF model.*

If you already have the Benefit object, of course, you can get its SchemeNames more simply by using:-

```
var schemeNameQuery = benefit.SchemeNames;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by using a Junction Table. The Junction Table is your Joining Table. It will consist of two foreign Keys, SchemeNameID & BenefitID.

Check out this website for more on Junction Tables:

http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/

It helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer] Conditional on there existing or adding the SchemeNameBenefits model the following should work.

So it seems like the SchemeNameBenefits table is a many-to-many map, in this case use the benefit ID to get a collection of scheme ID's

```
var schemeIds = db.SchemeNamesBenefits.Where(map => map.BenefitID == id)
                                      .Select(map => map.SchemeNameID).ToArray();
```

Then pull back all the scheme name information for these scheme ID's

```
var result = db.SchemeNames.Where(scheme => schemeIds.Contains(scheme.SchemeNameID))
                           .OrderBy(scheme => scheme.SchemeNameId)
                           .Select(scheme => scheme.Name).ToArray();
```

Or in one query

```
 var result = db.SchemeNamesBenefits.Where(map => map.BenefitID == id)
                                    .SelectMany(map => db.SchemeNames
                                                         .Where(scheme => map.SchemeNameID == scheme.SchemeNameID)
                                                         .OrderBy(scheme => scheme.SchemeNameId)
                                                         .Select(scheme => scheme.Name)
                                                         .AsEnumerable())
                                    .ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks, but my issue here is really how do I use the SchemeNamesBenefits table in my code. I never created a model for this, it was just added as a table in the database when I created the other two models.

Comment: Hi Martin, as mentioned by Derek the SchemeNamesBenefits table is the map between schemes and benefits, so in this case a scheme can have many benefits and a benefit can be part of many schemes. You will have to populate this table yourself and then you would be able to query against it as in my answer above. Alternatively as per Iain's answer the provider will implicitly use it if you query against the benefits property of the SchemeName object.

Comment: I'm sure Martin understands what a junction table is. His problem is that SchemeNameBenefits *isn't part of his model*. I.e. there's no db.SchemeNameBenefits property.

Comment: Fair enough, got the wrong end of the stick then, will edit appropriately.