# How can I make my fluent API table publicly accessible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've added a many-many relationship table using extended `IdentityUsers` and my own custom table, `Systems`

`AppUser` derives from `IdentityUser`

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser() : base()
    {
        MySystems = new HashSet<MySystem>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<MySystem> MySystems { get; set; }
}
```

My custom system table is just standalone:

```
[Table("MySystem")]
public class MySystem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MySystem()
    {
        AppUsers = new HashSet<AppUser>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
```

And in the context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(appUser => appUser.MySystems)
            .WithMany(MySystem => MySystem.AppUsers)
            .Map(userMySystem =>
            {
                userMySystem.MapLeftKey("AppUserId");
                userMySystem.MapRightKey("MySystemId");
                userMySystem.ToTable("AspNetUserMySystems");
            });
    }
```

This has worked great, created the tables and I can get all of my newly created `MySystem` entries using e.g.

```
_context.MySystem.Find(1);
```

but now I can't get access to the also created `AspNetUserMySystems` entries using e.g.

```
_context.(table not available!)
```

How can I specify the created table to be publicly available?

Comment: Isn't it just a join table? Probably better not have access to it directly.

Comment: I can't join it because it's not available to select from in the `_context` instance?

Comment: It's been a while since if dabbled in EF but aren't join tables automatically created and handled by EF?

Comment: Well I guess my question then becomes how do I create a query that utilises an automatic EF join table... let's have a google...

Comment: wheres your db context defined?

Comment: I found an answer to query an automatic EF junction/ join table here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248860/querying-an-auto-generated-ef-junction-table